# how to call destructor on some of the objects in a Dynamic Array

Tags: c++, templates, placement-new

I finally got around to trying placement new to create an efficient dynamic array. the purpose is to understand how it works, not to replace class vector.  The constructor works. A block is allocated but uninitialized. As each element is added, it is initialized. But I don't see how to use placement delete to call the destructor on only those elements that exist. Can anyone explain that one? This code works for allocating the elements one by one as the array grows, but the delete is not right.

```
template<typename T>
class DynArray {
private:
  uint32_t capacity;
  uint32_t size;
  T* data;
  void* operator new(size_t sz, T* place) {
    return place;
  }
  void operator delete(void* p, DynArray* place) {
  }

public:
  DynArray(uint32_t capacity) :
     capacity(capacity), size(0), data((T*)new char[capacity*sizeof(T)]) {}
  void add(const T& v) {
        new(data+size++) T(v);
  }
  ~DynArray() {
     for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
       delete (this) &data[i];
     delete [] (char*)data;
  }
};
```

Comment: Where is the memory allocation?

Comment: in the constructor, not shown. will edit

Comment: Your code is undefined behavior, by the way. You cannot construct a random object in storage allocated for `char`s. Check out `std::aligned_storage` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actually found the only case (at least that I'm aware of) where you want to invoke the destructor manually:

```
  ~DynArray() {
     for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
       data[i].~T();
     delete [] (char*)data;
  }
```

Combined with a trivial class and `main`, you should get the expected results:

```
struct S {
    ~S() { std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << '\n'; }
};

int main() {
    DynArray<S> da{10};
    da.add(S{});
    return 0;
}
```

Note that you see the destructor called twice since `DynArray` takes objects by `const` reference, thus it has a temporary.

```
$./a.out 
S::~S()
S::~S()
```

Comment: With a move constructor for T, I could avoid that extra one right?

Comment: I really hate that I need placement syntax for this. The logical thing is to call a constructor on that object, but in C++ that creates a temp object, the constructor cannot be called as a method. It's a very long way to go.

Comment: @Dov - A move constructor would you let steal the temporary's values, but the temporary will still exist unless you did something similar to `emplace_back` where it constructors the object directly.

Comment: can you point me to an example of how to implement emplace? I would love to do that. I don't know the signature of the constructor in advance obviously.

Comment: @Dov - I'm not sure it's a good idea to try and mix multiple things right now while you're trying to learn placement `new` (one of the weirder things in C++ as it is).

Answer (score 3):

A placement `delete` doesn't make much sense since the destructor already does what a placement `delete` is supposed to do.

An ordinary `delete` calls the destructor and then releases the memory that was allocated for the object with `new`. However, unlike an ordinary `new`, a placement `new` does not allocate memory, it only initialises it. Therefore, a placement `delete` would only have to call the destructor of the object to be "deleted".

All you need is to call the destructor of each object of the array directly:

```
~DynArray() {
   for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
      data[i].~T();
}
```

---

Since C++17 you can also use the function template [`std::destroy`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/destroy) instead of directly calling the destructor:

```
~DynArray() {
   auto first = std::addressof(data[0]);
   auto last  = std::next(first, size);
   std::destroy(first, last);
}
```